# Script to copy directory of filenames to .txt file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

This should be fairly easy and I understand the logic of it but my shell scripting is rather beginner.

Basically, I have a directory with a hundred files or so, and I want to copy their filenames to a .txt file. One line per filename. I know I'd want a loop for all the files in the directory, copy name to text file, repeat until there are no more files but not sure how to write that out in a .sh file.

(Also, just out of pure curiosity, how would I omit the file extensions? In this case, they're all the same extension but potentially in the future they may not be, and while I need the extensions right now I may not in the future. I'm assuming there might be a flag for this or would I use '.' as a delimiter to stop copying at that point?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `ls -1 > filename`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be very easy with `ls`:

```
ls -1 [directory] > filename.txt
```

Note the flag `-1`, it tells `ls` to output filenames **one per line** regardless what the output is. Usually `ls` acts like `ls -C` if the stdout is a tty, and acts like `ls -1` otherwise. Explicitly specifying this flag forces `ls` to output one per line.

If you want to do it manually, this is an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd [directory]
for i in *
do
    echo "$i"
done > filename.txt
```

To omit extensions, you can use string replacement:

```
echo "${i%.*}"
```

Comment: Hah! Thank you! I think I'll spend this afternoon reading through a shell scripting book for these easy tasks.

Comment: @Chris I highly recommend [this one](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, you can do

```
ls <dirname> > files.txt
```

Comment: How about `-1`?

Comment: @iBug When printing directly to a file, it does that anyway

Comment: Thank you guys, really appreciate it!

Comment: And can confirm, it does print one per line without the `-1` flag, but assuming I wasn't printing directly to a file I'd need to use that.

Answer (score 1):

I alias `ls` to `ls -F`, so to avoid any extraneous characters in the output, you would do

```
printf "%s\n" * > ../filename.txt
```

I put the output txt file in a different directory so the list of files does not include "filename.txt"

If you want to omit file extensions:

```
printf "%s\n" * | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' > ../filename.txt
```

Comment: I alias `ls` to add `--color=auto`, haha. And I alias `l` to `ls -F`.

Comment: @iBug could you explain why you alias that?

Comment: @Chris I don't think there's much to explain. Just personal preferences.

Comment: You don't need `sed`. It's overheaded for this simple task.

Comment: @iBug, what alternative would you suggest, keeping in mind that I don't hold the filename in a variable.

Comment: @glennjackman If you don't use a variable for file names, then `sed` is a fair move. I wouldn't suggest `awk` in this case as it's essentially the same.